# Save NSNumber in plist, not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsnumber

So I'm new to Obj-C (with experience in C and C++) and I've been trying stuff.
Quite simply, I want to save and load the score and level of the user as they progress.
I have 3 functions, `getFilePath`, `loadData` and `savaData`.

My `getFilePath` and `loadData` seem to work fine but I'm not able to get the `saveData` to work.

here is my code for it:

```
 -(void)saveData
 {
    NSNumber *updatedScore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
    NSNumber *updatedLevel = [NSNumber numberWithInt:level];
    NSLog(@"The level im saving is %@",updatedLevel);
    NSLog(@"The score im saving is %@",updatedScore);
    NSMutableArray *value = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:updatedLevel,updatedScore, nil];
    [value writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
}

-(NSString *)getFilePath
{
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"the path is %@",pathArray);
    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"saved.plist"];
}
```

My `NSLog` messages return the right values and the user progresses levels,but I'm not able to save them.

Comment: is it give some error??

Comment: Post `getFilePath` method

Comment: Can you show us `getFilePath`? An error in the path is a very common source of this sort of problem.

Comment: It doesn't give an error, but it doesn't save the values when I reload them on launching the app again (outside Debug mode)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the `getFilePath` method is using `NSDocumentationDirectory` rather than `NSDocumentDirectory`. Unfortunately, Xcode's auto-complete logic makes it all too easy to pick the wrong one.

---

Two further suggestions:

1. You should probably be checking the result of `writeTofile`, perhaps something like:

   ```
   NSArray *array1 = @[@1, @5, @3.423];
   BOOL success = [array1 writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
   NSAssert(success, @"%s: write failed", __FUNCTION__);
   ```
2. Personally, since I often use this pattern for creating a string that references the path of a file in the `NSDocumentDirectory` directory, I created a code snippet for it which eliminates the opportunity for me to mistype this. It gives me "auto complete" for several lines of code. So, suppose I have the following two lines in my code:

   ```
   NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
   NSString *path          = [documentsPath stringByAppendingString:<#filename#>];
   ```

   Clearly, use whatever code you want, but the key is to use `<#filename#>` placeholder for the parameter to `stringByAppendingString`. Then, as described in the [Creating a Custom Code Snippet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet.html) documentation (or see NSHipster's [discussion on the topic](http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/)), you can drag these two lines of code to the snippet library give it a good name (and just as importantly, a good shortcut, I use "`documentsPath`" for my shortcut). Now, in the future, I can just start typing "`documentsPath`" in my code, and I'll be prompted with these two lines of code.

   Since I've started using this particular code snippet, I've never made a mistake about accidentally grabbing the wrong value instead of `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Comment: Thanks a ton ! Worked like a dream !

Comment: +1 For **Xcode's auto-complete logic makes it all too easy to pick the wrong one**

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for writeToFile:atomically:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a) specifies that only the types `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary` can be written to file.

To write `NSNumber` data to a file look into alternative serialization methods like: [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSPropertyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nspropertylistserialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: So how can I save an NSNumber ?

Comment: @user3046579 `NSNumber` works fine (despite what the documentation says). The problem is `NSDocumentationDirectory`.